# MySQLdb UPDATE hangs

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using MySQLdb module for Python to make some simple queries. When I do a certain UPDATE, it hangs for a while and finally gives this error:

> operational error (1205 'lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting
>   transaction')

The code I'm using is the following:

```
def unselectAll():
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='user', passwd='', db='mydatabase')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('UPDATE MYTABLE SET Selected=0')
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print 'ERROR ' + e.args[0] + ': ' + e.args[1]
```

If I try to use that query in console, works perfectly. Also, if connecting without db parameter and using mydatabase.MYTABLE at the query doesn't work either.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because the `UPDATE` isn't getting commited - have you tried `autocommit=True` for the connection? As in

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='user', passwd='', db='mydatabase', autocommit=True)
```

or maybe even

```
db.autocommit(True)
```

after you've created the connection.

Comment: execution from shell takes milliseconds, that's why I don't understand where the problem is

Comment: Commit solved my problem partially, but the timeout problem seems to be solved when database is created and closed into every function instead of passing the cursor to another function

Comment: MySQL doesn't actually support `cursors` so the `cursor` in `MySQLdb` is just an emulation. Maybe this open/close issue will be improved in future versions...